# Setting a Value to 40 cells while waiting 3 seconds between each set

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to set the values of D2 - D42 to FALSE, but I need to have about 3 seconds in between each update. So D3, wait for 3 seconds, D4, etc. I have other scripts that are tied to having a value of FALSE that take some time to run, which is why I need the sleep to happen. Here is what I have so far:

```
function rebuild() {
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D2:D42').setValue("FALSE");
Utilities.sleep(4000);
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

This doesn't exactly work like I thought it would. It just waits for 3 seconds then populates all the values at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function rebuild() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  for(var i=0;i<41;i++) {
    sh.getRange(2 + i,4,1,1).setValue("FALSE");
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(3000);
  }
}
```

This has been tested.  Works fine.